# Why peak1d won't miss a peak if it exists?

Tags: python, algorithm, proof

I saw the `peak1d` algorithm in [here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf) and on [Peak finding algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929108/peak-finding-algorithm).

I can't understand why it **surely** finds a peak if it exists. It seems that we are deciding to go with one half and can miss a peak on the other. I don't understand how comes you can apply a "binary search" technique for a random array (The array has no prior attribute).

How can I prove that `if there is at least one peak in`a`the following algorithm will find one of the peak`.

```
import random
a = [random.randint(0,100) for i in xrange(10)]

def peak1d(a,i,j):
    m = (i+j)/2
    if a[m-1] <= a[m] >= a[m+1]:
        return m
    elif a[m-1] > a[m]:
        return peak1d(a,i,m)
    elif a[m]<a[m+1]:
        return peak1d(a,m+1,j)


print a[peak1d(a,0,len(a))]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, `a[m-1] <= a[m] >= a[m+1]`, we have a peak.

In case 2, `a[m-1] > a[m]`, suppose we walk along the list, heading left. We may find higher and higher elements for a while, but eventually, one of two things will happen:

1. We find an element less than or equal to the one we just looked at. Then the one we just passed is a peak.
2. We hit the start of the list. Then the first element is a peak.

Thus, the first half of the list has a peak somewhere, and we can just look at that half. We don't need to consider the second half.

Case 3 is equivalent to case 2. We only need to consider the second half of the list, by the same reasoning.

Note that your implementation of the peak-finding algorithm is wrong. It doesn't handle the endpoints of the list correctly.

Comment: In my implementation tail and head can't be a peak, a peak needs 2 neighbors. It still not clear to me why it is true, let's say this array `[17,...,17 , 15, 14 ,..., 28,29,27]` in the first iteration you will choose the left half, and you will miss the `29` peak.

Comment: @0x90: If a peak needs two neighbors, then this algorithm doesn't work. Take a closer look at the definition; peaks don't need two neighbors. (The SO post you linked skipped part of the definition; the PDF *it* links has the full definition.) As for your example, it doesn't matter whether we miss the 29 peak, because we'll find a 17 peak. If we tried the second half, we'd miss all those 17 peaks. We only need to find one peak. (Note that those 17s count as peaks.)

Comment: replace those 17 with `[100,99,98,97,..., 17, 15, 14 , ..., 28,29,27]`, the first iteration makes you to choose the left side but there is no peak there so the algorithm(as implemented in the pdf) can't find in O(log(n)) a peak, and might miss one

Comment: @0x90: 100 is a peak. Really, take a look at the definition of "peak" as given in the lecture slides. Both PDFs allow the endpoints to be peaks.

Comment: My main claim is, you can't look in part of a list, assuming there are no prior properties it holds. and you can't deduce you searched for all the array.

Comment: This algorithm is not guaranteed to find the highest peak, only *a* peak. Basically, it will find a local maximiser, which has the property that the elements on either side are smaller, not a global maximiser, which has the property that all other elements are smaller.

Comment: You are since there is padding with minus infinity. in the video there is no padding [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtSuA80QTyo]

Comment: @0x90: In the video, they define that an endpoint is a peak if its single neighbor is less than it. Take a look at 17:40.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, I understand it finds a local maximum. the question why is there a case where there is a peak but the algorithm will announce there is no peak ?

Comment: @0x90: There is no such case. There is *always* a peak, and the algorithm will *always* find one. (Your implementation is broken, so your implementation won't necessarily find a peak, but a correct implementation will.)